# Is it okay to to make the lock transient for a Serializable class?

Tags: java, serialization, concurrency, locking

I have a class that implements `Serializable` and I protect the invariant of this class via a *lock* object which is of type `Object`. Is it okay to make it *transient* or can it have any unwanted side effects?

Code :

```
class MyClass implements Serializable{

 private final transient lock = new Object();
  ....
}
```

Comment: Yes, that will work.  `transient` only impacts serialization.

Comment: And make sure the lock is `static` too.

Comment: Why you want to make lock `transient`? After deserialization you will need some lock to synchronize on your methods. Are you going to initialize it later? Will `final` let that happen?

Comment: @Pshemo what other options for locking do I have?

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza: Of course the lock must not be static! The usual intent of such a lock Object is to provide fine grained synchronization for some method, and by sharing the lock across instances of MyClass this would be counteracted!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fine, as long as you [recreate the object upon de-serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4811615/deserialize-a-transient-member-of-an-object-to-a-non-null-default-in-java) so that you have something to synchronize on.

Also, you'll probably have to [remove the `final` modifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2968876/final-transient-fields-and-serialization).

It's up to you to decide whether this is worth the hassle.

Comment: I do not want to go through the hassle of recreating the lock object upon de-serialization. So I would like to remove both *final* as well as `transient` modifiers. Can I use any built in lock object for this case?

Comment: @Geek: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I have a class that can be persisted in disk and that class needs to ensure that its shared state is well protected because mutiple threads can access that state at the same time.

Comment: @Geek: And you don't want to serialize the lock?

Comment: I don't mind serializing the lock but since I am using `Object` as the lock , I had to make it transient.

Comment: @Geek: If you don't mind serializing it, just keep it non-`transient` and you're done.

Comment: but then I will have a non-transient,non serializable object inside a serializable object. Isn't that code smelly? Or am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: @Geek: You are missing the fact that `Object` is perfectly serializable out of the box.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26952/discussion-between-geek-and-npe)

Comment: @NPE: No, `Object` is not serializable. Try `out.writeObject(new Object())` and it will throw `java.io.NotSerializableException`.

Answer (score 8):

What you should do is use an empty array (even `new Object[0]`) instead.
Empty arrays are serializable whereas `new Object()` isn't.

Just do:

```
private final Object lock = new Object[0];
```

Automatic (de)serialization will work as expected, a lock will be recreated. It might take a little bit more memory than `new Object()`, but it should be negligible, and serialized space will also increase by a few bytes.

But it is definitely the simplest solution if you want to avoid custom serialization.

Comment: Worked for me. I think this is the most straighforward solution. Potential drawback would be that empty array takes 16 bytes of heap, whereas empty object takes 8. In most circumstances it does not matter and does not warrant removal of `final` and `transient` + `readObject()` implementation.