# use of Object o = new Object()

Tags: java, object

I have used -

```
Object o = new Object();
```

for thread synchronizations and this is helpful because making the lock object private encapsulates the lock so that client code cannot acquire it, but don't know any other use of this.
 
<del>What are the other reasons that Object class is not abstract?</del> In which other situation I can use above code?

Comment: "Denial of service attacks"? What do you mean by that?

Comment: "protect the object from denial of service attacks" but how?

Comment: I usually just use it to demonstrate how to create new objects to Java/OOP newbies.

Comment: I just mean to say - If class A uses intrinsic locks for synchronization and if some client takes lock on class A, then A instance won't be able to cater the the client.. couldn't found the another way to describe this, if you have another technical name then pls edit this.

Comment: @Falcon: "Denial of service" is a security term, nothing to do with thread synchronization.

Comment: @skaffman - Isn't this security of code, if another code locks the object

Comment: @Falcon: No, it's nothing to do with security, it's about safety. Two different things.

Comment: @Falcon Maby you are right, but the term DOS - "Denial Of Service" has another meaning, so it can be very confusing trying to figure out what you mean when you write it in the wrong context.

Comment: @skaffman - hmm.. got it.. removing the line.. thanks :)

Comment: If you are going to the trouble of creating your own lock, you would use `Lock` IMHO.  Even using an Object for synchronizaton isn't so useful these days.

Comment: @Falcon: I can appreciate what you meant. I suppose I didn't think of that as security, considering security has effectively failed if rogue code is now running in your JVM and it has access to your `ClassLoader` and it has access to your objects.

Comment: @Adam Paynte - Thanks and agreed.

Comment: @Peter, there is one overlooked aspect of `synhcronized(object)` it survives thread.stop(), so it the code is truly critical library code, synchronized is a bit more robust.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why java.lang.Object is not abstract?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2117689/why-java-lang-object-is-not-abstract)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main practical utility of just creating a generic object would be to leverage its locking capabilities (e.g., `wait()` and `notify()`).  But this may be what you are referring to by "denial of service", since use of these methods can help manage threads and *potentially* help in a defense of DoS.  (but that is really app specific, and not inherent to the purpose of these methods within Object)

The reason(s) why Object is not abstract is already discussed at length here:

[Why java.lang.Object is not abstract?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2117689/why-java-lang-object-is-not-abstract)