# Why Object Class is not abstract?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why java.lang.Object is not abstract?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2117689/why-java-lang-object-is-not-abstract)

I never need to make a object of Object Class an It think a lot of programmer have not done this thing before. If you ever need to make a Object class then please share that condition otherwise I want to know why Object Class is not abstract while we never make object of Object class.

Answer (score 4):

I do create objects of type `Object` which are very useful when using locks in multithreading applications. This perfectly answers the question, I need an object of any type that I can lock on and the first thing that comes to mind is `Object`

```
public class MultiThreadedClass{
     Object lock = new Object();
     // ...
     public void useSharedResource(){
          synchronized(lock){
              ...
          }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have actually created a new Objects to use for synchronization & locking.