# Is Object a superclass of abstract classes?

Tags: java, object, inheritance

I am wondering whether `Object` is superclasses of "loose" abstract classes as well, i.e. the abstract classes that do not extend other abstract classes. I don't see this mattering much in effect. But how is the "formal" wording on this one when putting things all together.

The following support and contradict the Q in the subject line the way i see it:

Supporting ("Yes" to Q above): i.) A concrete class can inherit from an abstract one, ii.) every class is a descendant of `Object`, and iii.) every class (except `Object`) has exactly one superclass. If `Object` weren't a superclass to abstract classes, 
then (iii) should necessarily be violated for the special case of `Object`-- "a class can have two superclasses iff one of them is `Object` and the other is an abstract one."

Contradicting ("No" to Q): An abstract class cannot be sub to a concrete one, and `Object` is concrete. But then, this too can be phrased as "for the special case of `Object` class."

Is it more on one side than the other, or is it merely something like "a bit of both-- exceptional for the `Object` class". thanks in advance.

**Note**: i read the discussions on 
[Why java.lang.Object is not abstract?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2117689/why-java-lang-object-is-not-abstract).

**Correcting my obvious mistake in the original message above:**
Abstract classes can apparently inherit from concrete ones. That makes Object their superclass as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The think I think you are confused about is that it is legal for an abstract class to inherit a Concrete class. It's fairly rare, but it can happen. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7496010/544198) shows quite a few examples of such.

Comment: Thanks for the link-- that makes it. i`ve been missing abstract classes inheriting from concrete ones.

Comment: Nearly all of the examples there are of concrete classes extending other concrete classes. In fact, the only counterexample I see is an example class-hierarchy from ASP.NET (which is not Java). If you see a different counterexample there, why not copy it into your answer here, rather than sending readers to comb through that page?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, `Object` is a supertype of every abstract class, and — uniquely — is even a supertype of interfaces.

> An abstract class cannot be sub to a concrete one, […]

That is not true.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, all "loose" abstract classes inherit `Object`. It's not very common for abstract classes to inherit concrete classes, but it is legal.