# What are objects of the Object type useful for

Tags: java, object, new-operator

I saw the below code under practice questions in SCJP book

```
Object obj = new Object();
```

First I thought it might be an error since I didn't use statement like this. Now I understand it is a valid statement.

I just want to understand what is the practical use of this if any. What can you use an object of the `Object` type (rather than of a class derived from `Object`) for?

Comment: How else would you create a new instance of the `Object` class?

Comment: @JustinNiessner I believe he is asking what is the usefulness of creating a new instance of the Object class.

Comment: @JustinNiessner Why can't Object be an interface instead of concrete class? Since it is a class in Java what is the use of being a class instead of interface?

Comment: @Athiruban Object provides implementation for methods such as `#equals`, and only classes provide implementations, interfaces cannot. classes that do not specify a parent inherit from object, so they all inherit these methods. This is important - e.g. for collections - as testing if the object is in the collection can never be left undefined

Comment: @James, Object provides _default_ implementations for methods such as #equals.  An interface would work if nobody expected those methods to have default implementations.  I think the real reason is historical:  The roots of Java's Object and Class classes go all the way back to Smalltalk---way before anybody ever thought of `interface`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: Rationale of the Object class not being declared abstract](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/710362/java-rationale-of-the-object-class-not-being-declared-abstract)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The code declares a reference of type `Object`, and assigns a newly allocated `Object` instance to it.

Now, instances of class `Object` might seem pointless. However, they do have practical uses. One such use is locking:

```
...
synchronized (obj) {
   ...
}
...
```

Comment: Only answer that has anything to do with the question. +1

Answer (score 1):

It can be used for example for synchronization:

```
synchronized (obj) {
   ... 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A practical use is not so common (NPE answer is one example), but since every class inherits from Object, when you call its constructor, the constructor of Object class will be implicitly called at some time, so you will need the capability to construct a new Object.

```
public class Foo {   // implicitly inherits from Object
    public Foo() {
        super(); // Object default constructor call
    }
}

public class Bar extends Foo {
    public Bar() {
        super(); // Foo default constructor call
    }
}

Bar b = new Bar();  // new Bar() calls new Foo() that calls new Object()
```

It's important to note that the calls of super() (superclass constructor) will be inserted implicutly by compiler.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me that still we are implicitly using Object's constructor. It didn't strike me when I saw the question in SCJP book.

Answer (score 0):

With the new operator, you allocate memory for the object, and call its constructor.
Usually creating an instance of an Object class wont appear much in day to day coding. Its also important to know that every class you make extends from object.