# Suggestions for the Use of Class Object

Tags: java, class, object, instantiation

Are there any reasons why anyone would instantiate the class `Object`?  Why is the class instantiable at all?  Could it not have simply been an `abstract class`?

Comment: quite often is is used for something like `private Object lock = new Object();` for locking.

Comment: This question has already being answered:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710362/java-rationale-of-the-object-class-not-being-declared-abstract